# Test lambda returns different result from API gateway test and Postman

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, postman, aws-api-gateway

I have a Lambda function to pull out keys in Json.

It's able to pull out the key from my Lambda test event, but not if I send the same Json body using the API gateway method test or Postman. The lambda code is below:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):

    if 'name' in event.keys():
```

Here is the Json in my lambda test event and my post body in Postman:

```
{
  "name"   : "bob",
  "age"    : "5"
}
```

Comment: I highly recommend: `print(json.dumps(event, indent=2))`

Comment: APi gateway `aws_proxy` integration to lambda uses different `event` [format](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-input-format).

Answer (score 0):

When API-Gateway sends the Postman payload to Lambda is adds a whole bunch of extra information which you can view using print(event). If you want to use Lambda tests to simulate a Postman payload then you will need to change the Lambda test payload to same.

Try something like this:
1. Send a payload via Postman and use print(event) in your Lambda to see what that payload looks like.
2. Copy the payload that you got into step (1) into the Lambda test case.

Voila, your Lambda test and Postman call should yield the same result.

To access JSON objects sent by Postman you will now need to use `dict = json.loads(event['body'])`